# RegSetValueEx: creating a DWORD value with the const BYTE data type

Tags: c, winapi

I tried to search for this question, but did not find anything so here I go:

I am trying to create a Registry value using **C code** and the `RegSetValueEx` function from the **WinAPI**, and data types that are defined in the official documentation. I used these definitions:

```
PTCHAR regValueName = TEXT("dwValue");
DWORD regValueType = REG_DWORD;
BYTE regData = 1;
const BYTE *pRegData = &regData;
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(regData);
```

The `HKEY` value was returned by the `RegCreateKeyEx` that I am not showing here.

This is how I am using the function:

```
setValueKey = RegSetValueEx(*pHandleResult, regValueName, reserved,
                            regValueType, pRegData, dataSize);
```

`setValueEx` is a `LONG` type.

As you can notice, I am trying to create a `DWORD` value, so I defined the `BYTE` regData value as 1, and then a const `BYTE` pointer to that value, but it is not working. The value is created but the data says:

> Invalid DWORD 32 bit value.

[image: Registry view]

I know that `BYTE` data type is defined as `unsiged char`, but I tried `'1'` and did not work. I also know that using a `DWORD` value as **regData** type works, but I would like to know why the official data type does not work for a `DWORD` value.

Can anyone tell me how can I create the value using the BYTE data type?

I did not put all the code, but I will if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason of not using DWORD for `regData`?

Comment: There is not. I just want to know why I cannot use the BYTE data type. It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: The fact that there is type coercion in `C` which allows to automatically convert BYTE to DWORD in assignments does not oblige Microsoft engineers to do the same in the `regedit` GUI.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, @fukanchik. It could explain why the function success.

Comment: Why someone still uses TCHAR? It is year 2016.

Comment: What type would you use? WCHAR?

Comment: Why are you using TCHAR? Do you really target non Unicode systems like Win 98.

Comment: Not really. I am trying to learn WinAPI and thought writing portable code would be better. Should I code using only UNICODE? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `TCHAR` vs `CHAR` vs `WCHAR` is not relevant to this question. Please keep on topic.  The issue at hand is the size of the `REG_DWORD` data, keep focused on that.

Comment: @Remy It's perfectly relevant for a comment. Absolutely on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to store a `DWORD` but give it a `BYTE`. First, this means that a part of the DWORD will be undefined. Second, and more serious, `datasize` will be 1 but that is not valid for a DWORD value. It needs to be 4 instead.

The type to be stored, the pointer to that value and the size for that value all must be correct.

```
LPCTSTR regValueName = TEXT("dwValue");
DWORD regValueType = REG_DWORD;
DWORD regData = 1;
const BYTE *pRegData = (BYTE *) &regData;
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(regData);

setValueKey = RegSetValueEx(*pHandleResult, regValueName, reserved,
                            regValueType, pRegData, dataSize);
```

Or simply:

```
DWORD regData = 1;
setValueKey = RegSetValueEx(*pHandleResult, TEXT("dwValue"), reserved,
                            REG_DWORD, (BYTE *) &regData, sizeof(regData));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me how can I create the value using the BYTE data type?

A `BYTE` is only 1 byte in size, but the Registry is expecting a `REG_DWORD` value to be 4 bytes in size.  So you must read/write 4 bytes, no more and no less, when dealing with a `REG_DWORD` value.

If your code has a value stored in a `BYTE` and you want to write it to the Registry as a `REG_DWORD`, you must extend it to a `DWORD` first, eg:

```
BYTE value = 1;
...
DWORD regDATA = value; // <-- here
BYTE *pRegData = (BYTE*) &regData;
```

Otherwise, if you truly want to write a `BYTE` value to the Registry using only 1 byte, you must use `REG_BINARY` instead of `REG_DWORD`.

See MSDN for more details:

[Registry Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884.aspx)